More network sites to see advertising test [updated with phase 2]
We’ve been exploring the concept of using open auction to manage advertising on some Stack Exchange sites. Under this model, advertisers (who have been organized into categories based on their products) “bid” for an advertising spot. There is a floor price - a minimum price for the spot, and all bids must exceed that floor price. At this time, only the Mathematics Stack Exchange site (currently in a small-scale test) uses the open auction model.
Advertisers have expressed interest in advertising to sites outside of the technology Stack Exchange sites. These sites have been largely devoid of advertising (although the sites have been eligible for advertising). This initiative aims to help us better understand potential new revenue opportunities and possibly refine our ad strategy in the future while delivering relevant ads to users of this site.
Mathematics experiment success
We began an open auction experiment on the Mathematics site on October 1, 2024. Since then, we’ve seen bids from over 200 advertisers, delivered over 36,000 ad impressions, and saw a 400% relative lift in click-through rate, which demonstrates engagement from the Mathematics community and confirms the relevance of the ads being delivered to Mathematics in the month of October. Tight category controls have also resulted in no ads reported by community members via the “Report this ad” function.
The experiment on Mathematics currently has three “Allowed Advertiser” Categories, which are Education & Training, Computers and Consumer Electronics, and Finance.
Phased approach for rolling out to more sites
Phase 1 sites
With the success of the open auction experiment on Mathematics, we’d like to scale the experiment to more sites in a phased approach. The first phase of sites we will release the open auction experiment to are the sites listed below.  We will launch this phase of the experiment on November 13, 2024.



Site Name
URL
Announcement Post




Anime & Manga
anime.stackexchange.com
link


Ebooks
ebooks.stackexchange.com
link


English Language & Usage
english.stackexchange.com
link


Literature
literature.stackexchange.com
link


Astronomy
astronomy.stackexchange.com
link


Biology
biology.stackexchange.com
link


Chemistry
chemistry.stackexchange.com
link


Cryptography
crypto.stackexchange.com
link


Earth Science
earthscience.stackexchange.com
link


Geographic Information Systems
gis.stackexchange.com
link


History of Science and Mathematics
hsm.stackexchange.com
link


Mathematica
mathematica.stackexchange.com
link


Medical Sciences
medicalsciences.stackexchange.com
link


Physics
physics.stackexchange.com
link


Psychology & Neuroscience
psychology.stackexchange.com
link


Space Exploration
space.stackexchange.com
link



The “Allowed Advertiser” Categories for the sites above include Education & Training; Computers & Consumer Electronics; News, Books & Publications; Scientific Equipment & Services.
Note - the Allowed Advertiser Categories might change over time based on the results after each phased launch and associated sites.
Phase 2 sites
Phase 2 sites will launch on December 3, 2024.



Site Name
URL
Announcement Post




Amateur Radio
ham.stackexchange.com
link


Board & Card Games
boardgames.stackexchange.com
link


Bricks
bricks.stackexchange.com
link


Chess
chess.stackexchange.com
link


Constructed Languages
conlang.stackexchange.com
url-ligo


Genealogy & Family History**
genealogy.stackexchange.com
link


History
history.stackexchange.com
link


Lifehacks
lifehacks.stackexchange.com
link


Mythology & Folklore
mythology.stackexchange.com
link


Philosophy
philosophy.stackexchange.com
link


Photography
photo.stackexchange.com
link


Poker
poker.stackexchange.com
link


Puzzling
puzzling.stackexchange.com
link


Role-playing Games
rpg.stackexchange.com
link


Science Fiction & Fantasy**
scifi.stackexchange.com
link


Sound Design
sound.stackexchange.com
link


The Great Outdoors
outdoors.stackexchange.com
link


Video Production
video.stackexchange.com
link


Woodworking
woodworking.stackexchange.com
link


Worldbuilding
worldbuilding.stackexchange.com
link


Writing
writing.stackexchange.com
link


Gardening & Landscaping
gardening.stackexchange.com
link


Home Improvement
diy.stackexchange.com
link


Movies & TV
movies.stackexchange.com
link


Music Fans
musicfans.stackexchange.com
link


Music: Practice & Theory
music.stackexchange.com
link


Pets
pets.stackexchange.com
link


Bicycles
bicycles.stackexchange.com
link


Martial Arts
martialarts.stackexchange.com
link


Sports
sports.stackexchange.com
link


Expatriates
expatriates.stackexchange.com
link


Travel
travel.stackexchange.com
link


GenAI
genai.stackexchange.com
link


Cross Validated
stats.stackexchange.com
link



Strict controls and precautions
We’ve set strict floor price controls to manage the number and quality of ads that get served on each site, and we have an extensively vetted block list to prevent bids that are not relevant to users of our network sites. If we notice bids from advertisers that are technically allowed but may not be the best fit for each site, we can add those advertisers to the block list. These blocks allow us to keep the ads relevant for this site. If you see an ad that you feel doesn't fit on the site, please report it by clicking the “Report this ad” option underneath the ad.
This experiment will involve no new ad placements - only the existing ones will be utilized (represented in the image below). Our Creative Guidelines have not changed. There should not be any offensive or sensitive ads, as the filters should block them from being approved. If you notice that particular ads are less relevant or violate our advertising standards, please report them.
Open auction ads are compliant with our privacy policy. We give you control over your personal information, presenting you with a choice of whether to accept cookies that will allow your personal information to be used for targeted advertising. As always, you can review and update your cookie preferences by scrolling to the bottom of any webpage and clicking “Cookie Settings.”

What’s next?
Each impacted community will get a notice from the Community Management team, in addition to this broader MSE post. After the first phase of sites have had the open auction experiment live for one month, we will evaluate the results and decide whether to conclude the test or graduate the open auction experiment, which would keep it running on each site. We will keep this post updated regarding graduating the experiment and/or what sites may be included in the next phase if we see success (impacted sites will also get a notice if they are included in the next phase). The experiment could be paused or concluded early if major issues arise.

We might not like it, but selling screen space to advertisers is a much better way for SE Inc to make money (which it has to do somehow) than selling our data to data brokers and people training LLMs on it. So ... yay?

Carrot, just wondering, any reason those 16 sites were chosen in particular?

@Starship, we're rolling this out with sites grouped into families based on similar advertising category groups.  These happened to share many of the same categories.

Ads on Medical Sciences shouldn't be allowed; it would be like SE is taking candy from a baby (advertisers are unlikely to get anything from it.)

@Randal'Thor I mean, IF they post an official announcement that they will stop the AI pursuit, I'll be glad to whitelist some ads, provided that they are 1) relevant to the site, 2) from reputable sources, 3) with no  third parties proxies like google&friends involved in the hosting. Simply put, if for example SE wants to self-host  an AmiAmi ads on Anime.Se, I won't be against it.

That said, since they thought it was safe to dare the "anime ads" route, I am also betting on how long it will take before we get not-so-appropriate items listing.

Does everyone even get report ad buttons? I just received an ad on math.stachexchange.com that doesn't have one. (it was an ad for a company pretending to be paypal offering dev services... what that has to do with math is beyond me)

@Randal'Thor They're going to sell our data as well.  What on Earth makes you think they won't?

@StephenG-HelpUkraine They functionally already are. Google ads and analytics were already being used on the site. It's not like this change is the first time Google ads are being used on the site - it's just a minor change to how exactly those ads are selected. I'd be more concerned about the ad selection and increased risk of scummy ads than I would be about privacy - because again, nothing has changed. Without an ad blocker, your data is already being collected by at least Google and a bunch of other companies with tracking cookies

And here's me thinking that the mods would get at least a heads up about this according to the mod agreement. Apparently not.

@KevinB screenshotting it and reporting it on meta should be the way then. If the report ad buttons are broken, well, name and shame em?

The selection of Anime & Manga SE is interesting, given it has just 0.6 questions per day. Was there a specific reason it was chosen over more active similar sites with topic overlaps like Sci-Fi & Fantasy (9.1), Movies & TV (1.9), or Arqade (3.5)?

@MaartenBodewes - This doesn't qualify as a policy change, so there's no requirement for mods to be given advance notice, and I wouldn't consider this a major change to the site features either. As such there's no hard requirement for advance notice, but I'll note that I'd consider a MSE post satisfactory for the purpose of informing mods when required - moderators are the minimum requirement in cases where it's required, but there's certainly no reason that a broader announcement wouldn't count for that purpose as well.

When I see posts about increasing advertising, it makes me wonder if there will be any changes to the Reduce Ads privilege. Can you confirm that these changes only impact how advertisers buy space, but not where & to whom ads are displayed?

@Mithical Not a policy change according to who exactly? Slippery slope right there. In this case I do go along with that reasoning, but I would like to have a heads up next time. This so that any questions that can pop up from the mod team or later users can be answered and that if any (site specific) questions are asked on the sites meta can be addressed as well. Please do not assume that just posting on meta is enough, that's taking it too far. I do like that you followed it by posting on our own meta though, even if that put me a bit in a bit of a pickle due to lack of info.

@Philippe -- I've noticed that when I ask a question in the comments to an announcement, I NEVER get a response, even if my question-comment is highly upvotred. Am I asking in the wrong spot? Do I need to be posting my questions as an "answer" or separate post on Meta?  I have always been under the impression that comments are the right spot to ask for clarification, but that obviously isn't working. As this point, my assumption is that I am either asking in the wrong spot, or I am being blatantly ignored.

@AMtwo I think this is a more general problem in that it is unclear whether and when staff will read comments, whether and when staff will read answer responses, and whether they will reply to either whether they've read them or not. At different times I've both gotten the impression that it was rude to assume that something wasn't read just because it didn't get a reply, and also that it was rude to assume that a comment or answer to an announcement was read because there are too many of them.

@AMtwo Philippe answered your question about the Reduce Ads privilege on the physics se meta post: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14826/268384

For clarity: "report ads" reports it to the site mods, or to SE staff? (I assume the latter, but it'd be good to clarify in case mods start getting heat for bad ads appearing on their sites)

What does the ** mean after Genealogy & Family History and Science Fiction & Fantasy? Side note: it looks like your profile photo from your MSE profile isn't showing on Science Fiction & Fantasy.

@cocomac - I spotted that. Possibly just a formatting error?

@kaia - can confirm we don't get reports as mods

@Richard I was thinking maybe a footnote that got lost somewhere. Could be that too, though.

I suggest that we all turn on our ad-blockers (if we haven't already) until SE removes this or at least makes this opt-in/opt-out

@Randal'Thor As long as I don't make money for contributing content that helps build a useful resource, I don't care in the slightest about the company making money.

@KarlKnechtel - Personally, I think people should be able to offer cash bounties.

@Richard That's a terrible idea, see this declined feature-request.

@Starship - Both individuals who were arguing that 'money creates the wrong incentives' have since sold their shares in StackExchange for millions of dollars.

@Richard You may note that said individuals made their money from creating SE, not writing answers

@Starship - Evidently it creates the wrong incentives for little people, not the people in charge

Anyone can bid on those spots? Yeah, nothing bad has ever happened when random sellers shove their scam up people's butts via unregulated advertisements.

As a note, it seems like the Phase 1 sites are ordered alphabetically by URL, whereas the Phase 2 sites are ordered alphabetically by site name - but both sorts restart or stop being alphabetical partway through each list. Could this be made consistent and fixed one way or the other?

@Randal'Thor bold of you to assume they would even consider to stop training the LLMs

Nobody likes ads but this is probably the only realistic way of funding a company of this size. Anyone thinking that selling bloatware, AI-something pyramid schemes, bottled air (ie access to data already freely available) or other such sand castles is a longterm way to make profits is plain foolish.

@Lundin Sure, but doesn't mean that I need to like ads. I hate ads and I avoid seeing them wherever possible. I feel that by answering questions and editing other content I have done my side of the bargain. If SO needs more money they could probably ask for donations, I guess. But I still avoid spending time and attention on ads wherever possible. On the other hand of course they can put up as many ads as they like. It's their space.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution It is not really an issue though. First of all, regular users (>200 rep) can opt out of adds and I see nothing here suggesting that this has changed (Profile -> Settings -> Preferences -> Enable advertisements). Second, it is trivial to install ad blockers in your decent web browser (read: Firefox). If you are using an indecent web browser, well... enjoy your adds and built-in spyware tracking your browser history...

@Kaia: Ad reports specifically go to the relevant product team (staff). Neither site mods nor CMs in general see those reports. (Though there might be a CM or two who can access the relevant dashboard.) At least, this was true when I worked at Stack.

@Sasha - I note you've edited the question, but not addressed the issue of why two of the sites have special notation.

@Carot - Is there any reason why two of the sites have special notation?. I've asked on SFF:SE if you'd prefer to answer there - https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14157/20774

Online advertising providers were and still are basically an unethical scam, a vexatious practice that offloads all the responsibility for any potential questionable actions from those selling the ads space to third party companies specialized in evading customers rights and legal consequences.

The ads are compromised and used in a malvertising campaign? The company holds no responsibility for any damage caused to the site visitor, and the ads provided will probably evade those as well.

The ads providers are harvesting user data and may be violating local legal requirements? No matter the legal or ethical issues this may raise, the actual site owners hold no responsibility for whatever their chosen provider is doing.

The ads are inappropriate for the site rating, promote scams or illegal content? Best case scenario is that you will able to press a report button that... based on my personal experience having tried for years reporting bad ads on the Google platforms, does absolutely nothing. See for example all the PEGI-3 mobile games sharing online casino ads, adult ads appearing on kids' sites and apps or ads for scam apps (all the "free money" ones). Again, the actual owners of the site/game take no responsibility.


That is to say that, given that the network consists mostly of SO and SO users generally being tech-savvy, I expect that the majority of said userbase will be VERY wary around any form of third-party advertising.
I fear that the only hope the company has to realistically persuade its users to whitelist the site, is doing something quite rare nowadays and self-host the ads, thus taking full responsibility for their content.

I wonder what percentage of users on SO install an ad-blocker as a reflex? I personally don't know why anyone browses the internet without turning off ads, except out of ignorance.

You have been a fervent, articulate, and evidence-based critic of Stack Exchange for some time now, what would be your idea for the company to make a profit that would exclude advertisements?

They could knock off the stupid stuff and ask for donations. They could even self-host ads.

@Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні As SamB sugged, I think that the old company from Jeff age would have no issue to raise some funds thru a donation campaign, Wikipedia style. That said, in this contest the issue isn't even the ads by themselves, those would be tolerable to a degree- I would be fine with Microsoft Azure / Amazon AWS ads on SO for example. The real issue is the intermediary ads provider. I know companies think it is not realistically feasible to self host ads, but at the same time it is not realistic to expect the user to blindly trust unethical providers.

@samb the company’s expenses are something like $100M a year. Obviously the site should have been non-profit from the beginning, but there’s no path from where it is today to being donation-funded, and it’s disingenuous and unhelpful to act like that’s a real alternative.

@ꓢPArcheon I'm not very familiar with these aspects of the ads business - is there any reason to think that this "auction" system is somehow worse in terms of online ad providers than how ads were previously being served on these sites? That is, does this post relate to the overall state of advertising here or to something about this test specifically?

@BryanKrause IMHO the standard approach to ads most sites use nowadays is vexatious to the user and can only exist because of the inadequacy of the current laws framework. Companies are just able to offload their responsibility for whatever scam will be presented on THEIR site to the "ads provider", which in turn doesn't really take any responsibility for inappropriate or even malevolent content on their platform either. This is why most users nowadays install an ads blocker. Ask yourself, did anyone invent a device to censor ads on TV? no, because those can't damage you or steal your info

@BryanKrause to answer your question, there is nothing specific to THIS test here, just a general reminder that almost no one will see those ads in the first place under the current conditions. There are very few users left who would want to whitelist the network out of "charity", and unpopular choices will only push those few towards just blocking everything as well, like everyone else is already doing.

@ꓢPArcheon "Ask yourself, did anyone invent a device to censor ads on TV?" - yes, most DVRs. Let's not fool ourselves, while malicious ads and privacy are obviously a concern, most people block ads because they don't want to see ads.

@MaciejStachowski not worth discussing this here, but... is the next step in this reasoning claiming that piracy exist just to skip the ads that are included on retail  blu ray and DVD? Ads are a waste of time and people most of the time don't want to see them, but it took malwertising to really start fighting back seriously. Furthermore, even if we consider you view valid, the same conclusion is reached: you would whitelist only a site you really love and won't risk getting into issues with ads anywhere else.

I'd note this was previously mooted in 2019 and well, appears to be deeply unpopular.
I notice the question post here is very much centered around the process, and what the company intends to get out of it. I know there's generally vague promises of more resources for the community but what do the communities in question get out of it?
Also, as a initiative that affects a broader subset of communities, this is the first I've heard of it. Even if one might argue this is picking up an 'older' project, I feel like it would have been a nice thing to give a preview of this to moderators in general. One builds trust by communication, and the communication here has been lacking. There's a comment from a moderator on one of the sites affected in the main post indicating they weren't informed either.
I really do wish the company would do better with understanding that, there's a social contract between the company and community, and suddenly announcing something like this with no feedback, or seemingly a focus on the mechanics and the company's goals with little reference to the benefits the community might get feels... off. You're not selling this to management, an investor or even an advertiser. You're trying to sell it to a community that's jaded, and somewhat suspect of many of the initiatives the company takes, and the end results it seems to get.

meh, the goal here is simply to extract more cash from advertisers. How they source their ads has little effect on users and claims of increased click rate is nothing more than marketing to get companies to buy more ads (note how they gave no other info than a vague % increase.)  It's certainly exploitive to serve ads in this way, but not exploitive of the community, rather, exploitive of the companies buying ads.  SO presenting this as a benefit to the community is potentially exploitive, if there isn't clear accountability of the funds going to the improvement of the community.

or, at minimum, a clear indication that for a community to be worth hosting it needs to be bringing in X, and quarterly updates on how these communities are faring so people know what to expect.

It's ironic (and utterly sad) how the more the company mentions the importance of and respect for the community in blogs and other outward-facing communication, the less they are actually showing any of that respect or appreciation to the community itself.

IMHO, that social contract went out the window when Prosus bought the company. It's worth about the same as  now

Oh it started being ignored waaaaay before that.


Tight category controls have also resulted in no ads reported by
community members via the “Report this ad” function.

This is not a good metric to use.  Malicious ads can evade that reporting mechanism fairly easily.  In many cases, you can't tell that an ad is malicious until after you've clicked on it.  The ad can't be reported at that point because either 1) the malicious site hijacks your 'back' button preventing you from going back to the original page, or 2) you go back to the original page but when it re-loads you get an entirely different set of ads (so there's no way to report the malicious one).  By the time you detect the ad is malicious, there's no longer any way to report it.
On top of that, very few people would actually use that button even when an ad is obviously malicious.  Those buttons are always on top of or very close to the ad itself, and they're always tiny.  If you don't have perfect aim you'll end up clicking that ad that you've already determined is dangerous.  It's hard enough to do on a desktop, but on a touchscreen it's nigh impossible.  After one or two mis-clicks, you quickly train yourself to not even bother trying anymore.

And I'm sure that many cases where people bother to report, are false positives where people are just angry with the company the ad belongs to, on something totally not related to the ad, e.g. they had a delay in shipment, had a fight with their customer support etc. I've seen at least one such a case here on MSE once, and surely there are much more.

Also, the buttons that are on top of the ad, its almost impossible to know if the report button is actually by the site, or a fake report button in the ad. Which if you are suspicious of an ad, means that security best practice would be to not press a button that has a good chance of being malicious.

How much revenue do you believe you'll get per-user with ads?
Can I just pay to use the site somehow, in addition to volunteering my time, energy, and expertise?  Or is there no way around the gradual deterioration of everything into advertising space?

That's an interesting idea. I guess it would be possible to have an bidding not that bids for the ad space whenever you make a visit and then displays exactly nothing. That way one would pay a fair price (exactly the same any other advertiser would pay) and per use. Content contributors with reduced ads would need to buy less.

Why would you want to do that? I'm honestly curious. The idea of paying for a site for which one creates, improves, and manages content that is free and public seems to be the opposite of what the network (and any network like this) should want, and will likely quickly push away even more users, slowing down activity even more across the platform, and thereby attracting even less visitors.

If you’re willing to pay to avoid ads, just use a free adblocker

There is already a pending feature request for that, since 2009.

@Joachim there are hosting costs that need to be covered at a minimum. I hate ads, so I'd rather pay to keep the site online than have them serve ads and inevitably complain about people blocking ads as though malvertising campaigns had never happened and people who block ads aren't acting out of self-interest.  Note I am not suggesting a paywall, just an option to pay

Thanks, @ErinAnne. Yes, it would be a nice solution, I just fear that a lot of users - who already feel underappreciated - will leave.

yeah, they should probably fix the whole not appreciating the community thing, but I don't see that happening anytime soon either.

@Joachim Since the purpose of advertising is to extract money from users, viewing ads functions as a means of paying. If we must pay somehow to keep the site online, then we may as well have payment options for people who hate ads.

Or the site pay us for posting answers? :)

@rogerdpack so—I recognize that you're not serious. but. I do think it'd at least be interesting if SE Inc tried to be fair and used their available metrics (I'm sure I've seen some you've reached X people number on my profile) to reward people for their question / answer "utility" by either showing them fewer ads or, for some (likely earlier / Euler-prolific users) making the offer to pay them. Given operating costs I think even the "best" users could only be offered a pittance. But it'd be interesting. and probably have some bad incentives alongside it.

@rogerdpack weirdly I'm reminded that jury pay in Texas (where I am) was incredibly bad (I think $8/day and recently bumped to something less ridiculous but still bad). It might pay for the cost of parking near the downtown Houston courthouse if you park wisely. Actually making the meager payments cost enough that they encouraged you to donate the pay instead, which they could do in lumps. When I served on a civil suit jury for two weeks we all got a substantial bonus from both parties involved (ca. hundreds of $) by a mechanism I don't really understand. I could see SE operate like this.

like, I don't think it'll even happen, but the combination of "technically we could offer you a little for your answer if you use an approved payment provider like Paypal or Ko-fi; please plow it back into SE's costs instead" and "if you give us a link to an approved payment provider, we'll display it next to your Qs and As and maybe someone will reward you" (gross) at least seems logically consistent

@ErinAnne I would not want people to get money for posting on SE. They could never pay enough to be relevant anyway but it would encourages countless people to make bad posts which look good/get lots of views to get money.


We give you control over your personal information, presenting you with a choice of whether to accept cookies that will allow your personal information to be used for targeted advertising. As always, you can review and update your cookie preferences by scrolling to the bottom of any webpage and clicking “Cookie Settings.”

Will rejecting targeted advertising be included in the "Necessary cookies only"-button, or will it be separate, akin to the "Object to legitimate interests"-buttons that are in some of the sunsections of the cookie settings as shown below?


As far as I understand, "Necessary cookies only" normally activates only technically necessary or unavoidable data collection, such as login cookies or request headers.

@Greengrün绿色vertзеленый that's how it SHOULD work, but I think it's an extremely valid point to question, given .... Well... Given some sketchy decisions the company has made in recent history

If "necessary cookies only" doesn't turn off unnecessary data collection, then it would be flat out illegal in the EU. The GPDR requires to have an easy option to disable all unnecessary cookies.

@Greengrün绿色vertзеленый But it does already happen with "Legitimate interests", which have to be objected to independent of clicking "necessary cookies only" (often with several buttons in different places, even SE has 2 of them).

IIRC, GDPR explicitly forbids targeted advertising from being considered "necessary", no matter how your site is designed.

As a moderator on one of the phase 2 sites (pets) - I noticed there's no mention of what categories of advertisements are allowed for sites on this phase. Considering its not a tech, or finance sites, would there be more directly relevant categories for more niche/non tech sites?

I'd believe it's the same as phase 1, considering that Anime.SE is a recreation site, not a tech/finance site.

Well yes but I feel like that is another example of a site that is in the same circumstances as us

Wait, what?
Just to give a "userstory" that I don't expect is particularly uncommon: I saw this and was really surprised that network sites don't already see ads--why is the company leaving money on the table?! I guess that establishes 3 things:

Many users are using adblock on all devices, and functionally this will change nothing for them.
StackExchange (company) could be doing a better job communicating about its ad policy, if it believes that it's significantly more fair/less invasive than other companies. (A "please turn off your adblock" blocker banner would either make me block the popup or stop using the site, though.)
Likely, the people who will be most affected by this change are not the people expressing opinions here, and may not be registered users at all.


Historically, well, most of the smaller sites literally been seen as too small to matter. There's been a few initiatives to try to directly make money on the smaller sites, but quite often they just ended up forgotten for some reason

Bring it on! If it makes the CEO happy and could lead to the hiring of more CM's, I don't mind the ads.
/me already using anti-ad technology

Could this be made opt-in, or at least give communities the option to opt-out? I notice that, currently, the per-site meta announcements for Anime & Manga, English Language & Usage, Literature, Astronomy, Biology, Chemistry, Geographic Information Systems, Physics, Space Exploration, Chess, Constructed Languages, Puzzling, Role-Playing Games, Science Fiction & Fantasy, Worldbuilding, and Bicycles are downvoted.
I truly do think that some communities would opt-in, or not opt-out. Out of the 50 communities mentioned in this post, yes 16 of their per-site meta announcements are negatively scored, but 34 aren't. 29 of them have a score of 0, including 2 with an upvote, 2 with 2 upvotes. 8 of them have score above 0, and 2 of them have a score of 2. Of the 16 "First Phase" sites, 9 announcements are negatively scored, although they all have an upvote, 5 have at least 2 upvotes, and 2 even have 3 upvotes! Of the 34 "Second Phase" sites announcements, only 7 are downvoted, and of those 2 have an upvote. While obviously not every community would opt-in/not opt-out, I think some definitely would choose to keep the advertising test.
I understand this might be an unrealistic request, but I really do think this would be much better if it was opt-in/opt-out.

making ad space that's being sold opt-in would devalue the adspace and reduce profits. This is along the same lines as "can we move the ads to the footer instead? and then place a div over them so we can't see them?"

@KevinB I meant more have the communities opt in not each user.

History is cyclic and this isn't doing too bad in comparison. I feel like its less about advertising on its own than (from reading the comments) SO inc being exploitative, and the actual benefits for the communities involved being unclear.

"…this might be an unrealistic request…" I disagree, it is a unrealistic, pie-in-the-sky, request. I can't imagine any community not wanting to opt out, which would mean Stack Exchange is back at square one.

@Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні Plenty of people upvoted this announcement and some even the per site meta ones. Some people are okay with it

Some people being OK with it when the majority isn't suggests minority rule. Of course, there's neither majorities nor minorities here. SO.Inc. owns the service and can do what they want... but the majority that they depend on to make their service worthwhile hates this.

Worldbuilding Says NO

We don't want your ads. Remove them from our community and get rid of them from StackExchange.
That is all.

If you're going to add ads, at least put the ads to the side so it's not so distracting. Imagine you are scrolling through an answer and a colorful ad pops up. How annoying is that?

It seems problematic to me to add a large number of phase 2 sites to the list only in an edit to the question, without an announcement advertised separately in the "Featured on Meta" sidebar. This phase 2 will go unnoticed by many users, in this way. At the very least, I suggest adding "updated with phase 2" to the title of this question (I'll do it myself!).
(Of course, I am assuming that it wasn't an intentional decision by SE to try and sneak in more advertisements without pushback. Am I right?)

FWIW, they have also posted the announcement on each child meta.

"Of course, I am assuming that it wasn't an intentional decision by SE to try and sneak in more advertisements without pushback. Am I right?" - You assume this why?

@Starship There are precedents, but I don't want to assume malice here.

Why not do this on Meta Stack Exchange itself? It seems like this is where the announcements about limited advertising tests are being posted, so IMHO it would be a good idea to at least test it here.

Because they've already tested it on Mathematics, and the audience here is pretty limited.

How would one make targetted ads for meta? SE merch?

Dogfooding might be funny.

@LyndonGingerich Personally I don't think it would necessarily be funny per se, but maybe it would work.

@RobertLongson The audience here is pretty limited? Worldbuilding is in phase 2 and its audience is an itty-bitty fraction of the audience here. Any generic ad suitable for distribution to all of the participating stacks would be entirely suitable here.

As a user and contributor, I don't care about how you choose to sell ads. I don't even care about the ads - display porn site ads if you think you can make money from it because, why not!?
All I care about is if the ad comes with any sort of anti-privacy "tracking". Any kind of tracking to "serve me better ads" or "serve me personalised ads" will mean StackExchange will always be in my ad blocker blacklist.

"display porn site ads if you think you can make money from it because, why not!?" - You can't be serious. Think that through for a sec. I for one would leave if they intentionally did that.

Historically - NSFW ads have been one of the points of friction/loss of trust with the company. We've had more drama about that than tracking.

@Starship I was being sarcastic.

Bad taste sarcasm.

@ShadowWizard Worse than the 142 downvotes this Q has? ;)

Well, think the problem is, SE actually displayed NSFW ads more than once, so it's a touchy subject.

@ShadowWizard Ah, I get it now. Thanks for that insight into SE history.

I think that SE already gets more than enough money from giant corporations that want to use the SE software for their private purposes - why is advertising needed?

The purpose of SE (and every other company, to be fair) is to make as much money as possible. Advertising is "needed" because it results in more money.

You mean Teams, and I'm pretty sure it's not going as well as they planned, to say the least, otherwise we would have been in a much better place.

Even under a completely altruistic model, more money is more funds that can be spent to build the platform– better, more quickly, more extensively, etc. There isn't really such a think as "more than enough money" in a corporate context; more money will always (to a point) mean more freedom to do more stuff.

It might be less painful and more effective than other means of making money.

What work? You volunteer your service of your own accord. If you want to be paid, get a contract that says so, or else accept that you're donating your time to the world at large and someone somewhere is going to skim off the top of that. @elemtilas

Yeah, we generate the content. For free. And SE makes it available to the world. For free. If you want the money for yourself, find a better way for SE to earn it, because they're already profiting and you haven't demanded a thing from that money yet.
